# NullReferenceException when passing Action

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to pass a public function to a new form to handle some details and update the main form but i a getting a NullReferenceException on this line `eh.TextBox1.Text = dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ToString();`

The funny this about this is it doesnt happen untill i include the delegate if i take out the delegate(left hand side) the code doesnt crash(but obviously doesnt work)

`EditHeader eh = new EditHeader();` -> `EditHeader eh = new EditHeader(this.UpdateHeader);`

Here is the relevant code for form1

```c#
private void OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
            EditHeader eh = new EditHeader(this.UpdateHeader);
            eh.TextBox1.Text = dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ToString();
            eh.TextBox2.Text = e.ColumnIndex.ToString();
            eh.Show();
        }

        private void UpdateHeader(string indexVal) {
            string[] array = indexVal.Split(',');
            int index = int.Parse(array[0]);
            dt.Columns[index].ColumnName = array[1];
        }
```

And here is EditHeader(or form2)

```c#
private readonly Action<string> _UpdateHeader;

        public EditHeader() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EditHeader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        public EditHeader(Action<string> updateHeader) {
            _UpdateHeader = updateHeader;
        }

        public TextBox TextBox1 {
            get {
                return textBox1;
            }
            set {

            }
        }

        public TextBox TextBox2 {
            get {
                return textBox2;
            }
            set {

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            int index = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            string indexVal = index.ToString() + "," + textBox1.Text;
            _UpdateHeader(indexVal);
            this.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the zero-arg constructor is initializing the components.  When you call the constructor passing the action, the components don't get initialized, so eh.TextBox1 is null.

You can add a base call list with ": this()" to the definition of the constructor to get it to call the zero-arg constructor after the body of the action arg constructor ends.

Answer (score 2):

`InitializeComponent` is not being called.

Your constructor should look like:

```
public EditHeader(Action<string> updateHeader)
    : this()
{
    _UpdateHeader = updateHeader;
}
```